# Postgres won't let me log in

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use postgres but when I type:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

I get prompted for a password, which I've tried 'postgres' and my root password.  I get this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

How can I reset postgres to not prompt for a password?  I installed with homebrew, and I'd be just as happy uninstalling and reinstalling as changing the permissions.

I tried updating pg_hba.conf with this line to no success:

```
local all trust
```

Comment: I don't know if it works on MacOS but on Linux I usually do `su - postgres` while logged in as root, and then just `psql`, and it works.

Comment: ya that didn't work on mac unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The line in pg_hba.conf should be `local all all trust`.